# Is $f: \mathbb{R}_l \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = 1$ for $x\geq 0$ and $f(x) = -1$ for $x < 0$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of real numbers with standard topology.

Let $\mathbb{R}_l$ is the set of real numbers with lower limit topology.

Is $f: \mathbb{R}_l$ $\to \mathbb{R} $ given by
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x$ $\geq$ 0} \\
-1, & \text{if $x$ $\lt$ 0}  \\
\end{cases} 
$$
continuous?

I know that $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}_l$ for every open interval $(a,b)$.

It seems that if $(a,b)$ does not contain $1$ or $-1$, then  $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is the empty set.

If $(a,b)$ contains $1$, then $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is all non-negative real numbers.

If $(a,b)$ contains $-1$, then $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is all negative numbers.

$(a,b)$ contains both, then $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is all real numbers.

In all cases, $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is in lower limit topo, so $f$ is continuous.

Is this right?

Comment: Almost right. Instead of "is all non-negative numbers", I'd prefer if you wrote "is $[0,\infty)$", but that's taste. What is a mistake is that you wrote "If $(a,b)$ contains $1$" where you meant "contains $1$ but not $-1$", and similar for the other case. You meant the right thing, but didn't write what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. The easiest way to see it clearly is to regard $f$ as a function from $\Bbb R_\ell$ to $\{-1,1\}$ with the topology that $\{-1,1\}$ inherits from $\Bbb R$. This is the discrete topology, so the open sets in $\{-1,1\}$ are simply $\varnothing,\{-1\},\{1\}$, and of course $\{-1,1\}$ itself. The inverse images of these are $\varnothing$, $(\leftarrow,0)$, $[0,\to)$, and $\Bbb R_\ell$, respectively, all of which are open in $\Bbb R_\ell$, so $f$ is continuous.

By looking just at the range of $f$ (in its relative topology, of course) you avoid having to look at all of the open sets in $\Bbb R$: all you care about is their intersections with $\{-1,1\}$ anyway, since it’s those intersections that determine their inverse images under $f$.